# Quote of two sentences - use as subject?

Tags: quotes

One word to a full sentence can be the subject of a sentence:

> "Das ist ekelhaft!" als Ausschrei ist eine Äußerung des Ekels!

However, can I also chain two sentences in one quote and use them as the subject?

> "Das ist ekelhaft! Und ich hasse dich!" als Ausschrei ist eine Äußerung des Ekels!

Note that the purpose I am going for is a konjunktionalphrase with *als*, and I am not interested in indirect speech and do not intend to chain two separate quotes with conjunctions like *und*.

Answer (score 1):

You did it right.

But the noun *Ausschrei* does not exist and you can't use *das Ausschreien* either because it does **not** mean *to cry out* in an intransitive sense. Rather, it means the same as *jemanden ausschimpfen* but more loud and you have to name that jemand.

I recommend *der Aufschrei* instead, or *das Gekreisch*.

And mind the quotes. Those have to be low 99, high 66 in German.

Comment: Ah, I thought because of preposition "aus" and "schreien". Good to know, thanks!

Answer (score -2):

You would actually use the verb and "Äußerungen" in plural, and you would put the "und" outside the quotes. Janka already told you to use "Aufschrei" or, alternatively "Ausruf" instead of "Ausschrei", so:

> "Das ist ekelhaft!" und "Ich hasse dich!" als Aufschreie sind Äußerungen des Ekels.

Comment: My note at the end says "I [...] do not intend to chain two separate quotes with conjunctions like und".

Comment: So, you're intending to do it wrong, then?

Comment: To quote "Janka": "You did it right". Please argue with Janka, not me.